# Apache imported GoDaddy SSL shows up as self-signed

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssl, openssl

I'm working on Redhat6 with Apache2.

I have a wildcard cert for *.example.com installed on my IIS7 server. I exported it to PFX, moved it to the Linux server, converted it to key and cert with openssl.

I configured the VirtualHost with SSL as follows before restarting the httpd service:

```
 <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.key
  </IfModule>
```

When I try browsing the site, I get the following error:

```
The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a trusted certificate authority.
The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address.
```

When I view the Certificate Info from Chrome, it says the issuer is the Linux server and has no mention of the actual domain name. Looks like it's loading a different cert altogether.

Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is that your `ca-bundle.crt` is incomplete.  Since you mentioned Godaddy, grab a new copy of it instead of using the file you exported?  https://certs.godaddy.com/anonymous/repository.pki

Comment: The file you want is probably `gd_bundle.crt`.

Comment: Did you verify the contents of your cert? `openssl x509 -in /etc/ssl/certs/example.cer -text -noout`

Comment: I checked the contents of the cert and it looks fine...correct domain and GoDaddy all over. I also already tried downloading gd_bundle.crt and using that instead of ca-bundle.crt in the SSLCertificateChainFile directive but it did not change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that I forgot to include the NameVirtualHost *:443 directive in the virtual hosts config file, as well as adding the *:443 binding to the existing virtual host.